# Can a table get other table column data

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I need to create a select statement where the statement need to retrieve data from other table column data

eg.

```
   Table1              Table2 
   id                  id2
   age                 age2
```

**Select id, age from table 1 where id= id2**

Is that possible.

Comment: You can use inner join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use <kbd>[`INNER JOIN`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx)</kbd>**

```
SELECT 
T1.id,
T1.age
FROM Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
ON T1.id = T2.id2
```

[**DEMO using INNER JOIN**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae9289/1/0)

**You can use <kbd>[`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)</kbd>**

```
SELECT 
T1.id,
T1.age
FROM Table1 AS T1
WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 
  FROM Table2 AS T2
  WHERE T2.id2 = T1.id
);
```

**You can use <kbd>[`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)</kbd>**

```
SELECT 
T1.id,
T1.age
FROM Table1 AS T1
WHERE T1.id IN (SELECT T2.id2 FROM Table2 AS T2)
```

**Note:**

In the working demo the output consists of two rows. There are two entries in `tabel1` and three entries in `table2`. But there are only two matching entries found between these two tables. That's why output consists of only two rows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. It is called a JOIN and there are several types of JOINs. I suggest you read up on them on [SQL JOINs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id ,age 
 FROM TABLE 1
WHERE id IN (SELECT id2 FROM TABLE2);
```

OR

```
SELECT id ,age 
 FROM TABLE1 , TABLE2
WHERE id = id2 ;
```

OR

```
SELECT id ,age 
 FROM TABLE 1 , (SELECT id2 FROM TABLE2) TBL2
WHERE id = TBL2.id2 ;
```